# Why is hasOwnProperty being invoked generically here?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

The following function is mentioned in *Speaking Javascript: An In-Depth Guide for Programmers* by Axel Rauschmayer:

```
function getDefiningObject(obj, propKey) {
    obj = Object(obj); // make sure it’s an object
    while (obj && !{}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, propKey)) {
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
        // obj is null if we have reached the end
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Its purpose, as the author puts it, is "to [iterate] over the property chain of an object `obj` [and return] the first object that has an own property with the key `propKey`, or `null` if there is no such object".

I understand the overall reasoning here, but what I don't understand is why `{}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, propKey)` is being done rather than just `obj.hasOwnProperty(propKey)`. Any ideas?

Comment: it could be that `obj` is not of the structure you imagine it to be and `obj.hasOwnProperty` is not `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Often, developers will use `call` on a built-in type to ensure that they are getting the correct native behavior of a method and not some overridden behavior.

It is a protective measure that we really shouldn't have to use, but because Objects are so malleable in JavaScript, it guarantees we get the behavior we desire.

Imagine if someone (who, intentionally or accidentally) created an object like this:

```
function SuperObject(){
   this.foo = function(){
     // Something here
   };

   this.hasOwnProperty = 42;
}
```

And then, you came along (without having seen the implementation of the object) and wrote:

```
var mySuperObject = new SuperObject();
console.log("Does 'mySuperObject' instance have its own 'foo' property? " +
            mySuperObject.hasOwnProperty("foo"));
```

You'd get this:

```js
function SuperObject(){
  this.foo = function(){
    // Something here
  };
    
  this.hasOwnProperty = 42;
}


var mySuperObject = new SuperObject();

// Safe way:
console.log("Does 'mySuperObject' instance have its own 'foo' property? " +
             {}.hasOwnProperty.call(mySuperObject, "foo"));

// Unsafe way (fails):
console.log("Does 'mySuperObject' instance have its own 'foo' property? " +
             mySuperObject.hasOwnProperty("foo"));
```

So, instead we get code like this:

```
// This creates a new "fresh" (and unaltered) object with "object literal"
// syntax that you know doesn't override "hasOwnProperty"
{}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, propKey)

// This performs the same task, but uses the native prototype object
// of the built-in Object type that we also know hasn't been altered:
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, propKey)
```

It forces the `hasOwnProperty` to be looked up on the prototype chain of the native `Object`, while:

```
obj.hasOwnProperty(propKey)
```

relies on that property being available and correct on a particular instance of an object (`obj`).

Other popular examples of this are with the Array type:

```
// These work the same as the Object examples above, but just 
// do it for the Array type:
[].forEach.call(); // Array literal syntax
Array.prototype.forEach.call(); // Explicit array syntax
```

Comment: Man, JavaScript is just messed up

Comment: @Sadiq It certainly can seem that way, but once you get your head around it, it is extremely flexible and powerful.

Comment: @Sadiq if you're used to other languages, think about it like calling a static method on a base class rather than an instance method that could be overwritten

Comment: That analogy makes sense, I just wasn't sure why it was being done

Comment: @ScottMarcus JavaScript certainly has a number of good / cool features but it is really screwed up in a number of ways

Comment: @Sadiq It is "the" most mis-understood programming language I know of. But, many of its idiosyncrasies date back to the two weeks Brenden Eich (JavaScript's creator) was given by Netscape to build it.

Comment: It could be worse. It could be PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Because `obj.hasOwnProperty` would terribly fall if the object was defined like these:

```js
var obj = { hasOwnProperty: 123 };
```

```js
var obj = Object.create(null);
```

With `{}.hasOwnProperty` you get a reference to the desired function from `Object.prototype`, you don't need to worry about it being shadowed somewhere closer in the prototypical chain, or the object not inheriting from `Object.prototype`.

This is a design problem, because `hasOwnProperty` should have been a static method, but now it's too late to fix it. Another solution is implementing [HasOwnProperty](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-hasownproperty) manually:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop) !== undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to execute `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` on an object, and you attempt to use `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` you're making some assumptions:

- The object has a key named `"hasOwnProperty"`. This is easy to fail if you create objects using `Object.create(null)`.
- The object has a function at `obj.hasOwnProperty`. This is easy to fail if the object has a key that has been added named `"hasOwnProperty"`. You might think this is a rare case, but it's not uncommon to parse things such as query strings into objects, and query strings are user-supplied.

Using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)` you're reasonably guaranteed to have the method you want called on the object that's being passed in as input.

For utility purposes it's quite common to see something along the lines of:

```
function has(obj, prop) {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
}
```

Comment: I considered the first bullet point but notice that there's an `obj &&` guard there

Comment: @Sadiq, `Object.create(null)` is not `null`, it is an object with no prototype chain and truthy, so `obj &&` will have no effect.

Comment: Why'd he do it then?

Comment: @Sadiq, `obj &&` will have no effect on any objects that are passed in, per the context of the question as you asked it. `null` could *also* be passed in, which is what `obj &&` is a guard for.